# Get Data From MVC partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I defined a view for my master model and call the detail partial view in it.My master model contain a  list .How can I get data from my partial view when page post back to the server?
Here is my code :

OrderModel:

```
public string ShipName { get; set; }
public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
public IList<OrderDetailModel> OrderDetailModels { get; set; }
```

OrderDetailModel :

```
public int OrderID { get; set; }
public int Quantity { get; set; }
public int UnitPrice { get; set; }

public OrderModel OrderModel { get; set; }
```

OrderView

```
     @model MvcFirstSample.Models.OrderModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "create";
    }

    <h2>create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        //.....

    @Html.Partial("OrderDetail")
}
```

and this my Partial view for OrderDetailView:

```
@model MvcFirstSample.Models.OrderDetailModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OrderDetail";
}
Partial view OrderDetail
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitPrice)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UnitPrice)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnitPrice)
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try this code?

```
@model MvcFirstSample.Models.OrderModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "create";
    }

    <h2>create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        //.....

    @Html.Partial("OrderDetail", Model.OrderDetailModels)
}
```

and the Partial view will be

```
@model List<MvcFirstSample.Models.OrderDetailModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OrderDetail";
}
@* we need to looping the list of Order details here *@
```

Finally, please add the custom model binder for OrderModel type

I will add an example code very soon

Comment: your sending data is ok but i want to get the OrderDetailView's  data in OrderView's post back.

Comment: As you see, because the OrderView has a form that contains the OrderDetails, so if you submit that form, all data (Order & OrderDetails) will come to the server.

Comment: ok but when the page post back to the server my orderDetail property is empty in my OrderModel

Comment: Yes, that is a reason you have to make a custom Model Binder for OrderDetails model

Comment: i am using Automapper.Should i use custome Model Binder ?

Comment: It does not relate to the AutoMapper guys. Because you just write a custom binder that run before the action on the controller happening. So we can manual binding the OrderDetails there